# PHP imap_open() => [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED]

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm trying to set up an IMAP connection to a mail server, the problem is it fails with message:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(81) "Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed."
  [1]=> string(81) "Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed."
  [2]=> string(82) "Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed."
  [3]=> string(49) "[CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)"
}
```

The code that I use to open the connection is:

```
$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password');
```

I have tested the same syntax for my Gmail account and it works fine. I can connect to the `server.test.com` and also authenticate using thunderbird (IMAP - SSL - 993), so it's not really the mail server having a problem.

I've searched through Stack Overflow for this issue, but I haven't managed to solve it, below are all the solutions I have tried so far:

1. `$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password', null, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN'));`
2. `$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:995/pop3/ssl}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password');`
3. `$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password'); (The cert is valid)`
4. `$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:993/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password'); (The cert is valid)`
5. `$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:993/imap}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password');`
6. `$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:993/pop3}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password');`
7. `$mbox = imap_open('{server.test.com:993}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password');`

Any idea from where the problem can come from? I'll also post all the error messages I got for all the solutions mentioned above and also the mail server and php logs later.

Note: To represent the errors I'm using:

```
var_dump(imap_errors());
```

Comment: Only suggestion I'd make is to try using the non-SSL IMAP port 143 while running a network sniffer to see what's actually transpiring on the wire.

Comment: Do you know what software the remote server is using?   And are you absolutely sure your password is correct? :)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. @Max I'm very sure that the password is correct, as I have reset it and pasted it in the script (I double checked this). It's running Dovecot.

Comment: @AlexHowansky That was the next step if I would have not got by with this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the web server and mail server were running on the same server, I managed to connect with the server IP address:

```
$mbox = imap_open('{127.0.0.1:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'user@test.com', 'password');
```